# How SET_CAR/SET_CDR macros should be expanded?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson

Michelson [specification](http://tezos.gitlab.io/zeronet/whitedoc/michelson.html#annotations-and-macros) declares the following rule for expansion of `SET_CDR` macro

> SET_CDR @var %field =>  CAR %field ; PAIR @var

However, `%field` is supposed to be a field annotation of right element of a pair, but it's passed to the `CAR` which fetches the first one.

The same problem for `SET_CAR`.

It seems that this rule can be fixed like:

`SET_CDR @var %field => CDR %field; SWAP; PAIR @var;`

However, this approach loses a field annotation of the left element, but if I test the following script on the alphanet:

```
parameter unit;
storage unit;
code { DROP;
       PUSH int 1;
       PUSH int 2;
       PUSH int 3;
       PAIR %l %r;
       SET_CDR %r;
       DROP;
       UNIT; NIL operation; PAIR; };
```

I get

```
Well typed
Gas remaining: 399452 units remaining
{ parameter unit ;
  storage unit ;
  code { /* [ pair (unit @parameter) (unit @storage) ] */
         DROP
         /* [] */ ;
         PUSH int 1
         /* [ int ] */ ;
         PUSH int 2
         /* [ int : int ] */ ;
         PUSH int 3
         /* [ int : int : int ] */ ;
         PAIR %l %r
         /* [ pair (int %l) (int %r) : int ] */ ;
         SET_CDR %r
         /* [ pair (int %l @l) (int %r) ] */ ;
         DROP
         /* [] */ ;
         UNIT
         /* [ unit ] */ ;
         NIL operation
         /* [ list operation : unit ] */ ;
         PAIR
         /* [ pair (list operation) unit ] */ } }
```

So, the question is: how SET_CAR/SET_CDR should be expanded in pure Michelson instructions? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, in fact:

```
SET_CAR @var %field => { DUP; CAR %field; DROP; CDR @%%; SWAP; PAIR %field %@; }
SET_CDR @var %field => { DUP; CDR %field; DROP; CAR @%%; PAIR %@ %field; }
```

So, the `@var` is ignored (and indeed looks to be lost upon macro unexpansion).

You can see for yourself. One easy hack is to `tezos-client -l typecheck script <script>`. Due to the `-l` you will see (in the request to the typecheck_code RPC) the raw expanded code in JSON.